# I don't understand why one disk is missing a label in XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, disk

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 and I have an issue with the labels of my EXT formatted disks on my graphical desktop:

- Disk one is shown as `foo`. When I right click the disk and choose "Properties", this also shows `foo` in the name field.
- Disk two is shown as `4,0 TB Volume`. When I right click the disk and choose "Properties", this shows `bar`, which is the name I want this disk to have.

Why is the name/label for one disk showing but not the other? As far as I can tell, they are identical, as they were formatted at the same time and with the same filesystem (ext3 or ext4, I can't remember).

**edit**: Both of the disks are mounted at `/media/user/volumename` and `bar` is obviously called `bar` there as well, but XFCE does not seem to recognize that name when displaying the same disk on the desktop. Why is that?

**edit2**: Turns out that the partition is missing a label. By launching `sudo gparted` and examining the two disks, it clearly shows that the "Label" column exists for the `foo` partition, but not for the `bar` partition. However, I can't unmount it, I get this:

```
$ sudo umount /media/user/bar 
[sudo] password: 
umount: /media/user/bar: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
        the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

But nothing seems to be using it:

```
$ fuser -mv /dev/sdd2
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/sdd2:           root     kernel mount /media/user/bar
                     root     kernel knfsd /media/user/bar
```

Anyway, I guess the answer here is that I need to apply a label, somehow, to the partition for it to show.

Comment: Do you have the drive mounted? If so, unmount it.